# What causes and how to fix shading artifacts on curved surface?

Tags: modeling, normals

Here's what I'm talking about, I've been using boolean then tried to manually clean up topo to the best of my ability while trying to keep quads:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbNuw.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtmUs.png]

Is it just bad topology or is there something else I need to do to get rid of those artifacts?

Comment: Hello :). Are you using any *Bevel* or *Subdivision modifier* there?

Comment: Hello! I have tried using bevels with Weighted Normals, however to no avail. In the above pictures I am not using either of those though, I've added everything manually (filled the face where the hole is, Inset it a little, then extruded it inwards and turned the N-Gon into quads)

This is a closer look: https://i.imgur.com/DEum6Ak.png

Comment: Well, there may not be enough geometry, or it's non-planar :). I'd try *Subdivision modifier*, 2 levels and use edge creases where needed.

Comment: These shading artefacts are du to the irregularity, the difference between the rest of the cylinder and the diagonal lines. Have you tried it in rendered view? There's a good chance you won't be able to notice it in rendered.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Yes, you are correct, they are basically non existent once the model is textured. Thank you both for your answers!